# build error: An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception

Tags: java, ant, build

I have the following **error** when i try to build .I dont know where the problem i please help
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.

`Consult the following stack trace for details:`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation not found
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1153)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:145)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation not found
C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\payroll\nbproject\build-impl.xml:920: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\payroll\nbproject\build-impl.xml:260: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 34 seconds)

build line 920:    
<j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
and build line 260 
            <javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"  destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, you could easily find this at the top of your stack trace you have posted:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation not found`

You are missing a class file, or have a reference to a file which is not really used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just added the following library

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.9/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downloading the *jfreechart-1.0.9.jar* from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjfreechart109jar.htm)